# Free font similar to Viga with Polish characters?

Tags: typography, font-identification, resource-recommendations, web-fonts

I'm looking for a font similar to [Viga](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Viga) with Polish characters (Latin), preferably one from Google Web Fonts.

Comment: There are only 154 sans serif fonts on Google Web Fonts...have you looked through them to find something similar?

Comment: How about [Monda](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Monda)?

Comment: Thx, I use Monda.

Comment: Hi @Wojtek, if @Emre´s answer satisfies your question, you can mark his answer as accepted by checking it below the up/down vote buttons. This way, future visitors will have an easier time knowing what was the solution to your question, and at the same time, @Emre´s will gain credibility on this SE from your accept.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [Monda](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Monda).

For more ideas, go to Myfonts, select a font, and click on *More fonts like this*.